# Android: Как узнать имя пакета приложения?

Tags: android, java

Есть код:

```
private ArrayAdapter <String> plugins = null;
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List <ResolveInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
String[] appsList = new String[] { apps.toString() };
plugins = new ArrayAdapter < String > (context, simple_list_item_1.xml, appsList);
```

Задача: из названия приложения в appsList[i] узнать имя пакета.

Answer (score 1):

Вы уверены, что в appsList у вас названия приложений? Запустил ради проверки, получил одну длинную строку `[ResolveInfo{4056edf8 com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList...]`. Соответственно, заданный вопрос смысла не имеет.

Я считаю, что у вас в корне неверный подход к задаче. Лично я бы создал свой подкласс адаптера с переопределенным `getView()` и адаптеру передавал бы сразу список (или массив, не суть важно) из ResolveInfo. У объектов ResolveInfo внутри содержится вся необходимая информация.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот метод возвращает имя пакета **вашего** приложения

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```